# Xcode : 'XYChart/XYChartDataSourceItem.h' file not found ( Unity Project Exported in iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I created one project in unity and export it in iOS. I did some work on Unity-iPhone exported app like :-

1) Add button programmatically and set action on it. (This code i written in
 UnityViewControllerBase.mm class of method - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { } )

2) and opened storyboard file

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidAppear: animated];
        AppController_SendUnityViewControllerNotification(kUnityViewDidAppear);
        UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [but addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(buttonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [but setFrame:CGRectMake(52, 252, 215, 40)];
        [but setTitle:@"SHOW" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [but setExclusiveTouch:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:but]; 
   }

-(void) buttonClicked: (UIButton *) sender {
        UIStoryboard *myStory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        HomeViewController *homeVC = [myStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
       [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

This code run successfully.

Now, I used one chart Library XYChart written in Objective C.
Before using this library on Unity-iPhone exported app . I created one small demo project in xcode with objective c language and just drag and drop classes of XYChart library on my xcode project . it run successfully :-)

[image]

After this , I Drag and drop all classes of XYChart Library on my Unity-iPhone Exported app But i got error XYChart/XYChartDataSourceItem.h' file not found

[image]

Anyone tell me , How to solve this error in Unity-iPhone Exported App.
 Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

Finally , After Few hrs of grinding I resolved this issue.

I will share, How i Resolved it.

Added each framework missing reference of class

CoreGraphics
MobileCoreServices
QuartzCore

this framework needed while used XYChart Library.